# Check if a line has at least 2 different letters

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file that has a word on every line. I am trying to remove the lines that don't at least two different letters. For example, the file looks something like this:

```
words
books
aaa
letters 
zzzz
```

And I want the output file to look like this:

```
words
books
letters
```

I tried breaking every word in separate letters than grouping them together by using `uniq -c` and then `wc -l` but got stuck on the if statement. Also believe there must be an easier way of doing it, I just couldn't think of any other way of approaching this problem.

Comment: No, what I meant is that only words that contain the same letter should be removed, such as aaa but words such as dodo should remain in the file.

Comment: Should `a` be removed (only one letter — but only one character long); should `ßßß` be removed (only one letter, but not ASCII); should `!!!` be removed (only one character, but not a letter)? What about `aaA`? (And I dare not ask about `ßßs`).

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you mean *character* instead of letter (as in, you also want to delete lines that contain `...` or `11` even though `.` or `1` are not letters):

```
grep -vx -e '' -e '\(.\)\1*'
```

or:

```
grep -vx '\(\(.\)\2*\)\{0,1\}'
```

That is remove (`-v`) empty lines or lines that start with one character (`.`) followed by that same character (`\1` being a back-reference to what's captured by `\(...\)`) repeated 0 or more times (`*`) till the end of the line (`-x` anchors the pattern at the start and end of the line).

Portably, you can't use `egrep` or `grep -E` here as standard EREs don't have back references (only BREs do).

For lines that contain at least two different letters, ignoring the other types of characters (we'll use `[[:alpha:]]` here for *letter*, that is any character that is considered *alphabetical* in your locale):

```
grep -vx '[^[:alpha:]]*
[^[:alpha:]]*\([[:alpha:]]\)\([^[:alpha:]]*\1\)*[^[:alpha:]]*'
```

(on two lines, which is another way to pass two different patterns). Or:

```
grep -vx '[^[:alpha:]]*\([^[:alpha:]]*\([[:alpha:]]\)\([^[:alpha:]]*\2\)*[^[:alpha:]]*\)\{0,1\}'
```

That one would remove lines like `12345aaa` (only one letter) or `-+-+-+-` (no letter).

If you want to delete `Aaaa` lines as well (that is ignore case when comparing letters), add the `-i` option.

Note that it works at the character level, so it may not do what you expect if there are graphemes expressed with more than one character. For instance, it would delete a line like that output by:

```
 $ printf 'e\u0300e\u0301\n'
 èé
```

(assuming GNU `printf` or compatible), but not one like:

```
 $ printf '\ue8\ue9\n'
 èé
```

(where `e\u300` is the decomposed form and `\ue8` the precomposed form of the `è` grapheme; `e` (U+0065) and `è` (U+00E8) are *alphabetical*, but not the U+0300 or U+0301 combining grave/acute accents).

To work with graphemes, you can use `pcregrep` or GNU `grep` with it's `-P` option:

For the first case (at least two different grapheme clusters):

```
grep -vxP '(?:(\X)\1*)?'
```

For the second case (at least two different *letter* grapheme clusters):

```
grep -vxP '(?:(?=\PL)\X)*(?:((?=\pL)\X)(?:(?:(?=\PL)\X)*\1(?!\pM))*(?:(?=\PL)\X)*)?'
```

Where `(?=\PL)\X` is a non-letter grapheme cluster (a grapheme cluster (`\X`) provided `(?=...)` it starts with a non-letter (`\PL`) and `(?=\pL)\X` a letter grapheme cluster.

`\pL` matches on the *Letter* unicode properly. Contrary to the `[:alpha:]` POSIX character class, it also includes letters from non-alphabetical scripts.

Note that it would consider `e\u300\u301`, `e\u301\u300`, `\ue9\u300`, `\ue8\u301` as four different clusters even though they would all be a `e` with both an acute and grave accent.

Also beware of characters like `ﬃ` (U+FB03) that contain several letters in one *character*.

---

With PCRE, you can also take *positive* approaches:

- at least 2 different characters:

  ```
  grep -P '(.).*(?!\1).'
  ```
- at least 2 different letter characters:

  ```
  grep -P '(\pL).*(?!\1)\pL'
  ```
- at least 2 different grapheme clusters:

  ```
  grep -P '^\X*(\X)\X*(?!\1(?!\pM))\X'
  ```

  that one would not work properly with Koran Hangul in decomposed form (at least). PCRE (contrary to `perl`'s RE with `\b{g}`) doesn't have grapheme boundary operator (AFAIK) and has limited support for unicode properties. We're using `(?!\pM)` (which means in that context: "provided it's not followed by a combining mark character") as an approximation, but that doesn't work for multi-part Hangul *letters*/*syllable* characters where the *parts* don't have that property. It would delete `려련련` for instance. Now one may also argue that each *part* is a distinct *letter*...

  With `perl` 5.22 or above, you could write it:

  ```
  perl -Mopen=locale -lne 'print if /\b{g}(\X).*\b{g}(?!\1\b{g})\X/'
  ```
- at least 2 different *letter* grapheme clusters:

  ```
  grep -P '^\X*((?=\pL)\X)\X*(?!\1(?!\pM))(?=\pL)\X'
  ```

  Again, doesn't work on `려련련`. With `perl`:

  ```
  perl -Mopen=locale -lne 'print if /\b{g}(?=\pL)(\X).*\b{g}(?!\1\b{g})(?=\pL)\X/'
  ```

---

With `perl`, we can use more straightforward approaches like:

- at least 2 different characters:

  ```
  perl -Mopen=locale -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -lne '
    print if uniq(/./g) >= 2'
  ```
- at least 2 different letter characters:

  ```
  perl -Mopen=locale -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -lne '
    print if uniq(/\pL/g) >= 2'
  ```
- at least 2 different grapheme clusters:

  ```
  perl -Mopen=locale -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -lne '
    print if uniq(/\X/g) >= 2'
  ```
- at least 2 different *letter* grapheme clusters:

  ```
  perl -Mopen=locale -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -lne '
    print if uniq(grep /^\pL/, /\X/g) >= 2'
  ```

Answer (score 1):

According to your expected output - you want to skip words that have more than 2 **identical** characters:

**grep** approach:

```
grep -vE '(.)(\1){2,}' file
```

The utput:

```
words
books
letters
```

---

To modify the file *inplace* you may apply the following **sed** approach:

```
sed -Ei '/(.)(\1){2}/d' file
```

Comment: That removes lines that contain sequences of 3 times the same character which is not what is being asked AFAICT.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, how can you know? cause it has *being asked* initially **wrong**. It's obvious that the OP has confused in its description. *AFAICT* - is the crucial **keyword** in your comment

Answer (score 0):

Positive search of the query:

```
while read -r line; do 
    n=$(echo "$line" | egrep -o . | sort -u);
    [[ ${#n} -gt 1 ]] && echo "$line"; 
done < file
```

Comment: That removes lines like `"  x  "` or with some `echo` implementation: `-en`. ITYM `< <(cat < <(cat < <(cat < file)))` or maybe `< file` instead of `< <(cat file)`. See also [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting post. I knew it was inefficient but i didn't know a better solution. Nevertheless, I see you already took care of that :)